Custom PCB with Esp32-S3 isn't recognised by Device Manager for every board ordered
Two weeks ago I've ordered a custom PCB from fiveer. I received the schematics and ordered the PCB from JLCPCB.
After arrival I wanted to start developing on the board immediately but my Windows PC did not recognize every Board (5 total). I installed the necessary drivers from esspressif and then tried many more, to no avail.I've also contacted the creator, but he is on holiday for a week. Can anybody tell me what is the issue? My Mac also doesn't recognise the board.
I also tried pressing the BOOT and RST Buttons with many different combinations. I am using the Arduino IDE and other boards like the esp32 from NodeMCU work fine. I am a beginner in the Circuit world and needed something more specific than an Arduino, thus I bought this device
BOM
PICKPLACE
GERBER





Caleb Seeling - Hi, (a) Do you have the BOM for the parts which were actually used to construct the PCBs? For example, something concerning me are the unlabeled components, presumably intended to be ESD diodes, on the USB data lines. What part number was actually used there? (b) Can you [edit] the question and add a couple of photos of the completed PCBs, in case something "jumps out" to readers. (c) What else did you receive, in addition to the schematic, from the freelancer e.g. PCB layout in a tool like Easy EDA etc.? (d) Have you done any initial voltage checks with a DMM? TY

I have updated my Question to answer a-c, Regarding d) I have not done any voltage checks as I have never done this before. I will look into it.

Caleb Seeling - Thanks for the update, that gives something for readers to review. || If you've never done any voltage checking before, I'm not sure I can give enough useful instruction of using a DMM and what to do, all within a comment. I was suggesting just to do basic checks that the 5 V & 3.3 V power rails are present and the correct voltages, in case of "gross" power-related problems. If you're not confident using a DMM, that might be too much for me to ask.

Dumb question, but do you have a jumper wired in where the external power switch would be (SW1 to SW2)?

I'm not sure what you mean. I have no jumper cables connected to the board anywhere right now. The only cable that is connected, is the literal USB C input. The USB power Terminal is not used

@SamGibson English is not my first language so I looked it up. I do have a DMM and I will try to use it. I will give you an update

@CalebSeeling - OK. Dave Tweed has highlighted a likely problem in his comment. Now we have the PCB layout (at least top side), we see that what is shown on the schematic as a power switch was not put onto the physical PCB layout as a switch - but as a connector block (strange). Follow Dave's advice. This is the sort of thing that would be found using DMM measurements, as no 5 V should be found on the input to the voltage regulator, in the current configuration (without the jumper wire described by Dave). This shows why basic power checks are important :)

Ah that makes sense. Let me check

Thanks to both of you for your time

You need to install a short wire connecting SW1 and SW2 on the switch connector.
They connect "VUSB" to "+5V" and everything is powered from the latter.

Thanks Dave Tweed and Sam Gibson. I forgot that I asked for a connection for a switch to be implemented. You found the problem so fast. <3
